# Why does iPhone 13 running iOS 16.1.1 (changed from 15.5) change my app's behavior when auto copy/pasting?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, clipboard, ios16

I wrote an app which auto-pastes (pre)copied text into its interface.
When I ran that app under iOS 15.5 it displayed a toast message that the other app had pasted the text over.

It looked like the following:

**Red Highlight** is the toast message stating that this app pasted in text from the other app

**Green Highlight** is the text (789) that was pasted into this app in a scrollable `UITextView`

[image: app interface showing copied pasted text]

**Running Same App Under iOS 16.1.1**

I updated my phone to iOS 16.1.1 and now the app does something completely different.

Now it displays a message asking if I want to allow the paste.
It displays this every time copy / paste functionality is executed in the app.

[image: app running under 16.1.1]

**Swift Code Snippet For Copy / Paste**

Here's the very simple Swift code that handles this copying from clipboard in my app:

```
let noClipboard = "No Clipboard Data"
dataToSend = "\((UIPasteboard.general.string ?? noClipboard))"
   
if (dataToSend == noClipboard){
   outputMessages.text += "No data to send. Try again!\n"
   return
 }
 outputMessages.text += "\(dataToSend)\n"
```

**Main Questions**

1. Is there any way to make this only show up one time?
2. Is there any way to suppress this pop-up dialog?

**iOS Emulator Running 16.x**
I cannot presently reproduce this effect within XCode because all the emulators still run 15.5

[image: add simulator in xcode]

When will an emulator that runs iOS 16.1.1 be available?

Comment: This is part of a huge suite of security updates that iOS 16 introduced. I’m not sure about only showing it one time. But absolutely you will not be able to get around it. Just like you can’t get around the notifications auth request. Or microphone, camera, contacts, photos, etc… it is there to stop random apps from grabbing copied text which could contain sensitive data.

Comment: As for an iOS 16 simulator… download the latest version of Xcode. I presume you’re on 13.x. Download 14.x.

Comment: And to be pedantic, it's an iOS simulator, not an emulator (there is a difference). :)

Comment: @HangarRash haha, very true 

Comment: Major upvote on the semantics. So glad you pointed that out. I write Android apps in Kotlin also, so over there I run an emulator -- not merely a simulator.  Simulators are so inferior and it should always be noted that iOS runs simulator.  